# WM_NCHITTEST and HTTRANSPARENT blocks input from message loop

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, winapi, mfc

We have a user definable "dashboard". It is possible to add several components into this window. Some windows are browser controls (ActiveX controls created with CLSID_WebBrowser). This browser controls can show content from different sources in the internal web.

To avoid blocking of the application each browser control is hosted in its own thread. Reason here was that the ActiveX Webbrowser control is hosted in an STA and only loads and shows data when message loop is running and this may block other parts of the UI.

So we have one parent window containing child windows of type list control, tree control, statics and group boxes, mixed with some browser controls. Except the browser control, all controls belong to the same UI thread. But the threads use one input queue and AttachThreadInput was executed for each thread to attach it to the main thread.

**Now we face the following problem:**

When the user designs his screen with a group box and a web control inside it. the application locks when the user moves the mouse over the browser control and clicks or uses the mouse wheel. The application locks and doesn't accept any further input. If you minimize the application and activates it again, you can work on and input is accepted again.

**Reasons**

With the debugger and spy++ we found out, that any mouse event causes WM_NCHITTEST to be sent to the group box. The group box returns HTTRANSPARENT. But the underlying window is of a different thread. We can see that an infinite loop occurs an WM_NCHITEST messages are fired to the group box and the input is blocked until this loop gets interrupted (minimizing by showing the desktop).

We can read in the documentation that WM_NCHITTEST and HTTRANSPARENT are limited to windows of the same thread. And I can find 2 other article in the net that describe the same or similar problem.

**The simple solution**

The simple solution is just to take care that the browser controls are never covered by a group box or static control. So changing the Z-order is simple and works (groupbox must follow the windows of the different thread in Z-order)

**Question**

I would be interested if there is another way to get around this problem. Or if there is a way to prevent such input queue deadlocks. Or if somebody knows what is happening internally when this WM_NCHITTEST must handle windows from different threads.

Comment: You could try subclassing/superclassing the groupboxes to filter out the offending messages.

Comment: Also, did you try with `AttachThreadInput()`-ing your threads?

Comment: The threads are synchronized with AttachThreadInput. I missed that in my posting. I will add it.

Comment: @rodrigo: There is no way to capture WM_NCHITTEST for the group box. You never know what should happen. And You can't return something different. Returning HTCLIENT would cause the mouse input go into the group box, but it should be "transparent". And I have no influence on the code that is executed in the GetMessage routine...

Comment: That's just the tip of the iceberg of trouble that you are invoking by hacking this.  This titanic will sink for any message that's passed from the child to the parent, HTTRANSPARENT is merely the first one that sunk you.  There's another mountain of trouble awaiting you on an arbitrary other machine that uses hooks or screen readers, the kind that you can never debug.  Never, *never* do this.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Oh this software with this framework runs for 7 years now. Without any trouble. Or better without anybody using a groupbox and browser control in this sequence. The ActiveX has its own parent in its thread and the "neutral" parent has nearly no interaction with the parent window in the main thread. All real communication is done with PostMessage or SendMessgageTimeout... This is a real rare situation we have. So what is the alternative? I need windows that contain information from the web. Also this windows should not block the main thread...

Comment: Maybe it's a paint issue. When you minimize the window and then restore it, the controls tend to go back to their original z-order. When mouse moves over any button with lower z-order, the button z-order goes on top of group-box, it triggers paint messages. Although my theory wouldn't explain why the deadlock gets interrupted by minimize-restore. In any case, keeping the static controls at bottom of z-order is a simple solution.

Comment: It is in fact no paint issue. The windows are repainted and always show current information. The problem with the Z-Order is, that hot key activating, will no longer work. Alt-<letter> to jump to a specific control... this was the primary reason for the Z-Order Groupbox in front of Browser control....

Comment: Interesting problem and architecture. Out of curiosity, what will not work anymore if you don't `AttachThreadInput` the browser threads?